# Add character after specific character in sql server

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql, sql-function

I have a string and need to  add character ',' after each character'}'
and the string doesn't have fixed length

and need to add '[' in the start of text and ']' in the end of text

for example :

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `REPLACE()` here along with a concatenation:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable
SET val = '[' + REPLACE(val, '}{', '},{') + ']';
```